# How does the out parameter work internally?

Tags: c#, out

```
class fff {
    public static void jjj(out int j) {
        j = 88;
    }
}

//Main method
 int jfjf;
 fff.jjj(out jfjf);
```

In my main method I declare the `jfjf` variable which is not initialized in the runtime so I was wondering when I pass `jfjf` as the out argument to my `jjj(out int j)` method, what does the `int j` in the method refer to since the `jfjf` is not initialized?
I would like to know how this works internally.

Comment: `int j` is just a locally scoped reference variable/parameter. Same answer applies without the usage of `out` except that `jfjf` will be unchanged  after calling `jjj()`

Comment: Actually, `jfjf` is initialized to `0`

Comment: @Cid I assumed that it was not initialized because if I do not use the out parameter and try to pass jfjf as an argument, I get a compiler error. Could you please expand on this?

Comment: @Cid It's not initialised to anything. You can't use it until you assign a value to it.

Comment: @Cid, Re "*Actually, `jfjf` is initialized to `0`*",  [No](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#928-local-variables) "A local variable introduced by a local_variable_declaration is not automatically initialized and thus has no default value. Such a local variable is considered initially unassigned.". (And yes, it is [perfectly valid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#927-output-parameters) to use such a var as the arg for an `out` parameter.)

Comment: Thank you @DavidG. Cid was creating confusion her.

Comment: `what does the int j in the method refer to since the jfjf is not initialized?` - "not initialized" doesn't mean "nonexistent". It's an `int`, value type, local variable, totally on the stack, for as long as the function is being executed. It's value just has not been explicitly set to any value yet, but it's there, and exists, as soon as the function started being executed. Moreorless. If it were not `int`, but `MyClass`-typed variable, it would still be true: the variable itself is on the stack, and exists likewise, but the object on the heap it (maybe) points to - that's a different story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, the *address* of `jfjf` is passed to your method.

For a regular (non-out) int parameter, the parameter's value is passed to the method. For example, the first statement of the following code block

```
f(1);

void f(int i) {
   ...
}
```

compiles to the following CIL ([sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKEIDMAKHASgG5DCMAWAAjNgUagsYG9CBfWgkA)):

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.1   // Push the value 1 on the stack
IL_0001: call void Program::'<<Main>$>g__f|0_0'(int32) // Invoke the method
```

---

On the other hand, if we have an out parameter ([sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKEIDMAKAewFcEACWWqASgG5DCMAWGsqhmBxjQDehGmLo0AvDQAMrAgF82BIA=)):

```
f(out int i);

void f(out int i) {
    i = 0;
}
```

the *address* of `i` is passed to `f`:

```
IL_0000: ldloca.s 0  // Push the address of the local variable with index 0 on the stack
IL_0002: call void Program::'<<Main>$>g__f|0_0'(int32&)
```

When `f` assigns a value to `i`, the value is stored at the memory address provided by the calling method:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0     // Push argument 0 (= i's address) on the stack
IL_0001: ldc.i4.0    // Push 0 (the value we want to assign) on the stack
IL_0002: stind.i4    // Pop the value and the address from the stack, and store the value at the address
IL_0003: ret
```